# Using rscopus to retrieve non-aggregated Twitter data from an article in Scopus

Tags: twitter, scopus

Because of Twitter API constraints, I am attempting to scrape twitter data about a published article via the Scopus API using rscopus. Scopus integrates plumx data, which provides readers with social media metadata (twitter mentions, etc.) and also provides copies of the actual individual tweets.

However, the data I am able to access using rscopus is aggregated (see below). Does anyone know if scraping all the individual tweets is possible from the Scopus API?

```
library(rscopus)
```

First, you need an elsevier api key, which you can quickly retrieve here: https://dev.elsevier.com/

Set the api key and test:
options(elsevier_api_key = "put your key here")
have_api_key(api_key =) #should yield TRUE if you have correctly set key

Retrieve the plumx metrics using the article doi:

```
x = plumx_metrics("10.1016/S2352-4642(20)30250-9", "doi")
```

OR

```
type = "doi"
value = "10.1016/S2352-4642(20)30250-9"
res <- plumx_metrics(value, type)
```

When I read the data, I only get aggregated lists for how many tweets, facebook mentions, etc. However, every individual tweet is visible when in Scopus. Is there a way to get this data using the plumx_metrics function?

Answer (score 0):

You can't scrape the actual twitter data from PlumX

You can only see the number of times a Tweet has mentioned something

THis is a metric type API, it doesn't return the actual contents of the Tweet